# Personalization key not working SUP Native iOS

Tags: objective-c, sup

This is my code and i want to get the ACCOUNT list by using date as my personalization key.

```
    AC_FLOWPersonalizationParameters *pp=[AC_FLOWAC_FLOWDB getPersonalizationParameters];
    NSDate *date=@"2013-03-09";
    pp.PO_DATE_PK=date;
    [pp save];
    [PO_FLOWPO_FLOWDB synchronize];


     SUPObjectList *obj=[AC_FLOWGetACByDate findAll];
```

But i'm getting all account list and not by personalization key date

Comment: You need to delete the UDB data ie the device database before you do a syncronization everytime, And make sure you have enable cache partion checkbox in cache policy properties

Comment: Also you can refer my answer here regarding personalization keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348944/sup-personalization-key-via-native-android-search-button

Comment: What is the SUP version you are using .

Answer (score 0):

You should use synchronization parameters to filter the data. 
This synchronization parameter should be defined on the MBO (here AC_FLOWGetACByDate), and should be mapped to date attribute  in this MBO in the SUP SDK.